# concat two json objects using angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs, concatenation

Hello I'm trying to concat two JSON object to form a bigger json body. both these objects are form values which are assigned to a rootscope variable.

```
$rootScope.AString = angular.toJson(AModel);
    $rootScope.BString = angular.toJson(BModel);
    $rootScope.CString = BString.concat(AString);
```

But this does not work! I searched through all the documentation. there is no clear function to do this. please help!

Comment: Cant you do just a object with two properties: `Amodel` e `Bmodel`? Something like: `$rootScope.model = { AModel: AModel, BModel: BModel };`

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242927/deep-merge-objects-with-angularjs

Should work

Comment: converting to json makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by using spread operator(es6),
you will get the combined object of AModel and BModel at $rootScope.CModel.

```
$rootScope.CModel = {...$rootScope.AModel, ...$rootScope.BModel};
```