# How to merge complex JS objects

Tags: javascript

How can I merge two (or more) JS objects like this?

The result should contain all functions (like showUser and showOtherData) and events and requests-arrays should be merged as well.

```
var object1 = {
  events: {
    'app.activated': 'showUser'
  },
  requests: {
  },
  showUser: function() {
    console.log("es jhsod")
  },
};

var object2 = {
  events: {
    'app.destroyed': 'hideUser'
  },

  requests: {
    main: {
      url: 'http://example/api/main',
      data: {
        format: 'json'  
      }
    }
  },

  showOtherData: function() {
    console.log("foobar")
  },
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [deep merge objects with AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242927/deep-merge-objects-with-angularjs)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know there are already some implementations, but this is so much fun to write recursive functions. Check this one more `extend` function for your problem. It also supports unlimited number of arguments:

```
function extend() {

    var result = {}, obj;

    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        obj = arguments[i];
        for (var key in obj) {
            if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[key]) === '[object Object]') {
                if (typeof result[key] === 'undefined') {
                    result[key] = {};
                }
                result[key] = extend(result[key], obj[key]);
            } 
            else {
                result[key] = obj[key];
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(extend(object1, object2, object3));
```

**Demos:** http://jsfiddle.net/zgbwtp4g/, http://jsfiddle.net/zgbwtp4g/1

Comment: That is an awesome function. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way but there are various implementation online stemming from different libraries, i.e [lodash merge](https://lodash.com/docs#merge) or [jquery extend](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/). You can see the implementation of those and implement it yourself.

This seems to show a nice implementation: [merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242927/deep-merge-objects-with-angularjs)