# scope isn't updating on $apply use

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a piece of $scope text that should update dynamically.

```
<span ng-bind="user.balance"></span>
```

after pushing a button, new value of balance is received and should be displayed here.

```
$http.post('/transaction/send', transaction).success(function(sender) {
          console.log("http response");
          $scope.user = sender;
          console.log($scope.user.balance);
          $timeout(function() {$scope.$apply(); console.log("apply used");}, 1000);
        });
```

In console log anything is received and displayed  properly, but it still doesn't update scope in the view. What am I doing wrong?
I'm using $timeout to get rid of "$digest is already in use"

Comment: You should not put `$scope.$apply()` there, actually it is not needed as well.. Digest cycle will be triggered after success callback.. Your issue could be elsewhere

Comment: I think I remember seeing a similar scenario and `angular.extend($scope.user, sender);` would be used instead of `$scope.user = sender;` that way, you would merge the objects instead of assigning a new one.

Comment: Worked amazing, sir. You can make it an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`angular.extend(dst, src)`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend) instead of assigning a new object to your `$scope.user` variable.  By doing so, you will be merging the new properties into your older object; this will keep your binding working.  In the end, you should have something like this:

```
$http.post('/transaction/send', transaction).success(function(sender) {
      console.log("http response");
      angular.extend($scope.user, sender);
      console.log($scope.user.balance);
});
```

Mind you, this only does a shallow merge, for a deep merge, you should look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15310935/angularjs-extend-recursive) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242927/deep-merge-objects-with-angularjs).

Comment: this feels like a workaround.  is there a better way to write the binding?

Comment: @RobertLevy I personally don't see it as a workaround.  I also don't know if there's a better way to write the binding to solve this issue, but if there is, I'm interested in knowing how. :)